# What is "current_account.people.find" in Rails strong parameter example?

Tags: strong-parameters

I am new to Rails and am currently learning strong parameters in Rails 4 and following the below example from the official documentation:

```
    `class PeopleController < ActionController::Base
  # Using "Person.create(params[:person])" would raise an
  # ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes exception because it'd
  # be using mass assignment without an explicit permit step.
  # This is the recommended form:
  def create
    Person.create(person_params)
  end

  # This will pass with flying colors as long as there's a person key in the
  # parameters, otherwise it'll raise an ActionController::MissingParameter
  # exception, which will get caught by ActionController::Base and turned
  # into a 400 Bad Request reply.
  def update
    redirect_to current_account.people.find(params[:id]).tap { |person|
      person.update!(person_params)
    }
  end

  private
    # Using a private method to encapsulate the permissible parameters is
    # just a good pattern since you'll be able to reuse the same permit
    # list between create and update. Also, you can specialize this method
    # with per-user checking of permissible attributes.
    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
    end
end`
```

Question 1: 
What does `current_account.people.find` mean inside the update method?

Question 2:
Could someone please explain the person_params method. What is "params" inside the person_params method?

Answer (score 0):

1. `current_account` is a most likely a private method that returns an `Account` instance. `current_account.people.find(params[:id])` searches the `people` table for a person that belongs to the `current_account` and has an ID of `params[:id]`. `Object#tap` is a ruby method that yields a block with the current object, and then returns that object. In this case, the `Person` instance is updated inside the block and the returned from `tap`. Finally, `redirect_to` is a controller method that will redirect the request to a different path. `redirect_to` can take many different types of arguments, including an ActiveRecord model, a string, or a symbol. Passing it an ActiveRecord model will redirect the request to the model's resource path, which is defined in `routes.rb`. In this case, that path will most likely be `/people/:id`.
2. The params object is a hash containing parameter names and values. For example, the request `/people?name=Joe&age=34` will result in the following params object: `{name: 'Joe', age: '34'}`.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. As for question 1, as you mentioned that `current_account` is most likely a private method, then what is the most likely place where it might have got defined? Could you please give me an example?  Also, as of question 2, where is that `params` object has been defined? Is `PeopleController` class inheriting it from somewhere?

Comment: I think I need a complete example, probably a simple and short dummy code base to understand this in a concrete manner. Any help is much appreciated.